# How can i add an API in an ASP.NET Core Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-webapi

I have create an "ASP.NET Core Web App" Project in Visual Studio.

I want to add an API in this project ? I can create a separate Web API project but i want to put everything in the same project.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: `Is it possible ?` - Yes.

Comment: Did you intend to create a Razor Pages project?  And where does Blazor come in?

Comment: Non this is not a "Razor Pages" project but "ASP.NET Core Web App"

Comment: As Henk asked, where does Blazor fit in?  And if it does fit in, is it WebAssembly or server-side?  The answer to your question will depend on these details.

Comment: This is not a blazor project. This is an ASP.Net Core Web App. So it is a full server app

Comment: @Bob5421 - When you look in the New Project Dialog and Select "ASP.Net Core Web App" the description is about Razor pages. Document your question properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the web app project and also add a few API endpoints you could just add a folder (e.g. Api) at the project root where you can place your api-controllers.
Then in that folder you can add a class that will derive from `ControllerBase` and decorate it with `[ApiController]` attribute and a `[Route]` attribute.

This requires configuration of controllers in your Startup.cs though:

1. In `ConfigureServices()` add a call to `services.AddControllers();`
2. In `Configure` specify the `MapControllers()` option:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
   // other code
   endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you build an API solution, and then a separate Core Web App solution.

Otherwise you could try starting with a 'Blank Solution' and adding different projects to it.

Comment: I got your downvote right here, buster - CodeDonkey